# Get workbook type of embedded workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get the Workbook type or file extension from a workbook that is embedded in a SolidWorks model. I can get access to the Sheet pointer and subsequently the Application and Workbook pointer. What I don't know is how to get a value indicating that the workbook is one of the following:

- Excel workbook (.xlsx)
- Macro enabled workbook (.xlsm)
- Excel 97-2003 workbook (.xls)

The workbook does not reside on the hard-drive so using Workbook.Path returns "". I have also tried Workbook.Name, Workbook.FileFormat, and Sheet.Type to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: Try Workbook.FullName

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately that does not return the Excel workbook extension. Specifically: "Worksheet in Part1.SLDPRT" (Part1.SLDPRT is the SolidWorks model that the design table is embedded in).